# Timer Interval Inconsistent

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Timer that displays a simple countdown. The interval is set to 1 second. When executing, the delay in executing the timer routine is inconsistent, varying between 1 and 12 seconds. The timer routine only calculates a time difference and updates a label so it should execute within a second. Also, the system activity level is low. Does anyone have ideas of why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
Public Class frmForceUserOffDialog
    Dim WithEvents tmrForceOff As System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    ' --------------
    ' Initiate timer
    ' --------------
    tmrForceOff = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    tmrForceOff.Interval = 1000
    tmrForceOff.Enabled = True
    tmrForceOff.Start()

    Private Sub tmrForceOff_tick() Handles tmrForceOff.Tick
        Dim strCountDown As String

        Console.WriteLine("tmrForceOff_tick: " & DateTime.Now.ToString)

        Try
            strCountDown = formatTimeDifference(DateTime.Now, dtmForceOffTime)
            ' ----------------------------------------
            ' Countdown reached, terminate application
            ' ----------------------------------------
            If strCountDown = "" Then
                Application.Exit()
            Else
                ' ---------------------
                ' Update countdown time
                ' ---------------------
                strCountDown = formatTimeDifference(DateTime.Now, dtmForceOffTime)
                Try
                    lblCountdown.Text = strCountDown
                    lblCountdown.Refresh()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Those empty Try/Catch blocks will hide any errors from you, and dont seem at all needed for that code.  Forms Timers are not high precision so it wont tick at *exactly* 1sec intervals which the code seems to expect.  what does `formatTimeDifference` look like?

Comment: The Try-Catch adds overhead so you should test without it. And you have two of these every time the timer ticks.

Comment: In addition, timer messages (WM_TIMER) are low priority, so other messages may get posted first.